# White blinking when updating map style on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps-flutter

A Google map is displayed on the screen and the map style is updated with a dark theme when the map is created (onMapCreated)

The issue is a white blink when the style is changed and it is very visible due to the black theme transition. (Cf. video)

```
return GoogleMap(
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
              scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              circles: circles,
              markers: markers,
              initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _mapController = controller;
                final currentMapStyle = (_themeType == ThemeType.dark)
                    ? _darkMapStyle
                    : _normalMapStyle;
                _mapController.setMapStyle(currentMapStyle);
              },
            );
          }),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I placed the map in a stack.

This stack is filled with the map and a container.

The container is set to transparent after a small period (100ms).

Comment: Thanks for this tip! It occurs when I use mapsImplementation.useAndroidViewSurface = false and now I can hide flashing googlemaps behavior